# Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:7050: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, ubuntu, proxy, hyperledger-fabric, userland

I'm setting up a Hyperledger Fabric private network on Linux and got the message while running ./byfn.sh up

as I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and docker I think that the port needs to be changed in order to fix the problem, however, I have no clue in doing so. Any help would be appreciated.

```
alaa@ubuntu:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ sudo netstat -pna | grep 7050
tcp6       0      0 :::7050                   :::*                    LISTEN      3682/docker-proxy
```

did a netstat to check the port and its docker-proxy

```
alaa@ubuntu:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ sudo ./byfn.sh up
Starting with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI     delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
2019-05-19 14:07:22.820 UTC [main] main -> INFO 001 Exiting.....
LOCAL_VERSION=1.1.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0
Creating network "net_byfn" with the default driver
Creating volume "net_orderer.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver    
Creating volume "net_peer1.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer1.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating orderer.example.com    ... error
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ... 
Creating peer1.org1.example.com ... 
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... 
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ... done
Creating peer1.org1.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint     orderer.example.com     (60d170dbc933d3c2de9eacd1bb6c7842cf79a52b3a938c9e0e69d1bd55f5e1a9): Error     starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:7050: bind: address already in use'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
alaa@ubuntu:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ sudo netstat -pna | grep 7050
tcp6       0      0 :::7050                 :::*                    LISTEN          3682/docker-proxy
```

Comment: That's usually the error of some other container or host process already using that port.  Do you have a `docker run` command you can share, or any other source code; or are you just trying to run a pre-packaged application?

Comment: I'm following a tutorial from https://www.srcmake.com/home/fabric

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all for any kind of hyperledger tutorial, u better follow the official link, cos most of other sources were also taken from that one: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/

Secondly,bring down the network, stop&remove all running&previous containers, restart docker, re-run the network properly, should work fine:

```
$./byfn.sh down
$docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
$sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$sudo systemctl restart docker
$cd....fabric-samples/first-network
$./byfn.sh -m generate
$./byfn.sh -m up
```